# I lost a toolbar, where did it go?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I lost the toolbar with the text boxes and buttons and such that I could drag onto the form. What's that toolbar called that you can pin on the left with those items?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it, and also notice a couple of other toolbars were missing - just gone... I ended up re-installing VS and got em all back. Have no idea what happened...can you even remove toolbars from the View menu? I don't know, but the re-install got the toolbox back.